# When I add navigation in android studio, I get "Build gradle start up" error and "unable to resolve class val :13" errors

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I'm learning Kotlin language and when I wanted to add navigation I followed the steps suggested by the official site but my project didn't work

the error i encountered Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users....\Desktop\AndroidStudioProjeler\NavigationKotlin\build.gradle': 13: unable to resolve class val
@ line 13, column 13.
val nav_version = "2.3.5"
^
1 error

line 13 =val nav_version = "2.3.5"

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navigationkotlin"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

        val nav_version = "2.3.5"


    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
  

}
```

buil.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext.nav_version = "2.3.5"
  repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"

      val nav_version = "2.3.5"
      classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: |SOLVED| First I started a new project and then instead of defining it with "val" I defined it with "def" so =def nav_version = "2.3.0". I used 2.3.0 instead of 2.3.5 and removed the "implementation" brackets. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I started a new project and then instead of defining it with "val" I defined it with "def" so =def nav_version = "2.3.0". I used 2.3.0 instead of 2.3.5 and removed the "implementation" brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Just take a lower version(for example ->2.3.0)and change val to def

like a: def nav_version = "2.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

in project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.4.30'
    ext.navigationVersion = "2.3.5"
    repositories {
        //...
    }

    dependencies {
        //...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I changed version and it solved the problem.